# Find all descendents of the oldest ancestor in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have been trying for several days to figure out a solution to this issue but have not been able to come up with an answer.  What I have is a data set that looks like this:

```
Id      ParentId    Name
16      NULL        i_ss_16_Grommets
25      16          ss_25_Grommets
26      NULL        inactive_Grommets Clone
27      NULL        inactive_Grommets Clone Clone
46      25          ss_46_Grommets
47      46          ss_47_Grommets
48      47          Grommets
```

What I need to come up with is a function where I can pass an Id and then get the correct Name.  The way that I need to find the name involves a sort of reverse hierarchy since it is the youngest child in a branch that will be used.  For example, if I pass in Id 46, I need the function to return 'Grommets'.  If I pass in Id 47, I need to see 'Grommets', if I pass in Id 26, I would see 'inactive_Grommets Clone' since there are no descendents.

Even though it looks like I could just strip off anything with an underscore after it, I would not be able to since there is no guarantee that the child will be named the same.

Hopefully this makes sense.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please search for "recursive CTE" on this site. This question has been answered many times.

Comment: If this were Oracle, you could use `Connect By`. Since it is not, you will likely need to use recursive CTE. Maybe someone will jump by and give you a solution, but in the meantime I would google something like `CTE Connect by Implementation`

Comment: Thanks.  That got me on the right track.  I think I have figured it out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option with recursive CTE

```
DECLARE @Id int = 46
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT Id, ParentId, Name
  FROM dbo.test60
  WHERE Id = @Id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.Id, t.ParentId, t.Name
  FROM dbo.test60 t JOIN cte c ON t.ParentId = c.Id
  )
  SELECT TOP 1 *
  FROM cte
  ORDER BY Id DESC
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97d43/1)

Comment: Thanks.  The solution I came up with was very similar to yours.